# Unity3D - Images are low quantity when deploy on real devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem when deploy a unity product.

as title: my images are low quantity when deployed on real devices. It's normal on editor

I am using Mac OSX 10.8, Unity 4.2.1 and build to iOS version

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be in Image import settings.
Check your import settings. Image looks fine on editor but not on real device due to this.
[image: your default settings][image: Your iOS settings]

Either you **check override with higher quality** or by default keep high quality and **dont check**. you can select true color instead of compressed in Format for good image quality if performance is not the issue.